# Authenticated user is null in Laravel API without token

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.5

I am trying to save my data against logged in user id. But I am unable to do it. I am testing my api using Postman and using JWT auth. When I am logged in I get a token. I can save data against `user_id` with that token. But I don't want to pass that token on every request.

What I am trying here is to save `user_id` like this:

```
auth()->guard('api')->user();
```

My whole controller method:

```
$business = new Business();
$business->business_name = Input::get('business_name');
$business->business_url = Input::get('business_url');
$business->user_id = auth()->guard('api')->user();


$business->save();

$resultArray = ['status' => 1, 
    'message' => 'Business added!', 
    'dataArray' => $business
];
```

When i go with this error is

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null

When I log in I get a response like following:

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjgwMDAvYXBpL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTIzOTYxNDEwLCJleHAiOjE1MjM5OTc0MTAsIm5iZiI6MTUyMzk2MTQxMCwianRpIjoiVWppUVVXTENWNjQ4WTJWNyIsInN1YiI6MSwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.rIjmaEA1HdG64uolyKO9gVX6mqiQ8PN-a2YGO2-Palo",
    "currentUser": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Shahzad Hussain",
        "email": "shahzadshahg@hotmail.com",
        "created_at": "2018-04-17 05:55:55",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-17 05:55:55"
    }
}
```

I need your help and it will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You are trying to save a complete object of user in user_id field ?

Comment: no just user_id...

Comment: then what your should do it auth()->guard('api')->user()->id

Comment: when i do this it says Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: are you sure you are logged in ?

Comment: yeah i am ......

Comment: make sure you have proper middleware set to the controller you are calling this method

Comment: try using Auth::user() and see what you get

Comment: You need to pass the token you get after logging in with every request you need an authenticated user.

Comment: but i dont want to pass that token on every request

Comment: everytime same user login the token changed

Comment: what will i do when application will be live?

Comment: When a user is logged in save the token in client app and use that token in `Authorization` request header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
auth()->guard('api')->user();
```

to

```
\Auth::user()->id
```

or

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
        $this->currentUser = $auth->user();
}

$business->user_id = $this->currentUser->id;
```

or

```
auth()->user()->id
```

Comment: i follow all yours option when i follow  auth()->guard('api')->user()->id; it says trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @shahzad1122 try this auth()->guard()->user()->id, sorry this  auth()->guard('api')->user()->id does not work for me either

Comment: i also try this it says trying to get property of non-object

Comment: when i logged in i get a response like this:

Comment: {
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjgwMDAvYXBpL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTIzOTYxNDEwLCJleHAiOjE1MjM5OTc0MTAsIm5iZiI6MTUyMzk2MTQxMCwianRpIjoiVWppUVVXTENWNjQ4WTJWNyIsInN1YiI6MSwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.rIjmaEA1HdG64uolyKO9gVX6mqiQ8PN-a2YGO2-Palo",
    "currentUser": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Shahzad Hussain",
        "email": "shahzadshahg@hotmail.com",
        "created_at": "2018-04-17 05:55:55",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-17 05:55:55"
    }
}

Comment: i also add this into my question

Comment: @shahzad1122 try this auth()->guard('api')->user()->currentUser->id

Comment: Trying to get property 'currentUser' of non-object

Comment: Trying to get property 'currentUser' of non-object

Comment: can we have chat?

Comment: @shahzad1122 yes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169162/discussion-between-shahzad1122-and-mike-foxtech).